# Doomsday - How Does Pete Know

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode '[Doomsday](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doomsday)' (Series 2, Episode 13) the Doctor opens up [the Void](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Void) to pull the Daleks and Cybermen through and save the day. But Rose eventually gets pulled towards it *insert tense music* but her dad appears from a parallel universe to save her.

- But how does he know to appear at that exact point in time and space as he was in a different universe that these events didn't happen.
- Is this explained in the episode or just left for viewers imagination?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Earlier in [the episode](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/28-13.htm), they explained that the plan would likely result in the Doctor or Rose (or both) being dragged into the rift. Pete was present during this discussion as well as being aware of the timing involved:

> ROSE: But you stay on this side?
>
> MICKEY: **But you'll get pulled in.**
>
> DOCTOR: That's why I got these. (Magnaclamps) I'll just have to hold
>   on tight. I've been doing it all my life.
>
> ROSE: I'm supposed to go.
>
> ROSE: Mum.
>
> COMPUTER: **Reboot in one minute.**

Knowing the danger his daughter was in (and knowing the Doctor's plans down to the minute), it's reasonable to assume that Pete argued with Jackie and Mickey for a very brief time, then decided to jump back once the rift was opened.

His stance on arrival was a result of him steeling himself against the likely drag from the rift. He then caught Rose (as he planned to) and jaunted back to his own world with her in tow.

Comment: In-universe, this works, down to the smallest detail. Out of universe, it was poor editing common of teleporting scenes in many shows.